# Deep copy a dictionary changes order

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary called `wantedPoints`.
Performing a deep copy on the dictionary using this line:

```
copyWantedPoints = deepcopy(wantedPoints)
```

The result I get is this:

`wantedPoints`

```
{'AB12': [], 'GPS1': [], 'GPS3': [], 'BS3': [], 'AB41': [], 'C3': [], 'AB43': [], 'AB42': [], 'AB45': [], 'AB44': [], 'AB47': [], 'AB46': [], 'AB49': [], 'AB48': [], 'C2': [], 'C5': []}
```

`copyWantedPoints`

```
{'AB12': [], 'GPS1': [], 'GPS3': [], 'BS3': [], 'AB41': [], 'AB49': [], 'AB43': [], 'AB42': [], 'AB45': [], 'AB44': [], 'AB47': [], 'AB46': [], 'C3': [], 'AB48': [], 'C2': [], 'C5': []}
```

As you can see, everything stays the same except for two keys, `C3` and `AB49` changed their position in the dictionary.
Any idea why that happens?

Comment: I know that they are unordered but are you saying that copying a dictionary after initializing it changes it's order again? So copying a dictionary N times would result in N different keys orders?

Comment: I am saying that you are creating a new dict so it is possible to come in any order, it could be the same or completely different.

Comment: @Elia: you have a hash collision between those two keys: `hash('AB49') % 32` and `hash('C3') % 32` are the same. Their order depends on which key is inserted first. There are no other collisions in your dict, except for one other key pair (and the order doesn't change here because the insertion order is "correct").

Comment: @ajcr Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Try printing `wantedPoints` _before_ you do the deepcopy operation. You will see that the order of the keys is _not_ the same as the order in the literal you used to create the dictionary, and is, in fact, the same as the order shown for `copyWantedPoints`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Actually it prints the dictionary in the desired order which is the same as ''wantedPoints'' above.

Comment: For more info, so Martijn's excellent answer to [Why is the order in Python dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15479928/4014959)

Comment: Well in order to "bypass" this issue I just worked on the original dictionary and cleared it to its original values after. Not well done but suits my purpose. Will think twice about when to use a dictionary next time.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are not ordered containers, thats why, in case you want an ordered Continer take a look over [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Insertion order is not assured using dicts, `deepcopy` is just looping and copying all the values into a new dict, so the "order" of the keys can be diferen by implementation. Notice that `deepcopy` does not copy it like a C++ byte copy for example, it just takes all the keys and all the values(copying them too) and put them together.

Take a look at this [post](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/) of how a python dictionary example is implemented

Comment: Since i'm copying a dictionary (that must have been ordered by something, not just random) isn't it supposed to be in the same order since I haven't changed anything? Otherwise why only two points have changed their keys position?

Comment: @Ellia, dicts are not implemented for an ordered behaviour and they don't keep track of an insertion order (or any kind of order). Also, the order is not random as you suggest, it deals with the hashing of the keys.